# Create time-series graph in Shiny from user inputs

Tags: r, time-series, shiny, rstudio

Beginner here which would be very grateful for any assistance with the following.

I'm hoping to create a simple data app which allows me to:

- input 3 values (numerically between 1-11)
- output a time series graph.

If this is not possible, would direction in creating a logit function be plausible?

I know 3 values is scant, but I can add on as demanded.

Here is what I have

**ui.R**

```
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(   headerPanel("Time Series"),   sidebarPanel(
textInput(inputId="text1", label = "Input Text1"),
textInput(inputId="text2", label = "Input Text2"),
textInput(inputId="text2", label = "Input Text2"),
numericInput('Data', 'Time series',
             min = 0, max = 11)   ),   mainPanel(
plotOutput('plot1')   ) ))
```

**server.R**

```
    require(graphics) 
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  # Combine the selected variables into a new data frame   
  selectedData <-         reactive({   ts <- reactive({
    ts(selectedData(), input$ts)   })
    output$plot1 <- renderText({as.numeric(input$text1), as.numeric(input$text2, as.numeric(input$text3})
      par(mar = c(6.1, 4.1, 0, 1))
      plot(selectedData(),
           col = ts()$ts,
           pch = 20, cex = 3))   })    })
```

Comment: I cannot really get the gist of your end goal, can you elaborate on the time series (is it randomly generated? Inputted? etc.) and the role that you want the inputs to play?

Comment: Apologies. 
The goal is for the user to assign 3 numbers of choice between 0-11 as an input. (ui.R)
The output is a time series graph showing the lines connected (server.R).

Even more interesting would be a forecasting function but they is probably too complicated at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you are going to want to input multiple values at once, so a numeric input box for each point would be a bit cumbersome. I have taken the liberty of making it so you can copy and paste in comma delimited data:

(Note: the `value` is only specifying the default values, as soon as you click in the box they will clear.)

**ui.R**

```
shinyUI(
  pageWithSidebar(   
    headerPanel("Time Series"),   sidebarPanel(
    textInput("text", label = h6("Input comma delimited data"), value = "1.3, 2.9, 0.5, 2.1, 4.3")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput('tsplot')   
    ) 
  )
)
```

**server.R**

```
require(graphics) 

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
 output$tsplot <- renderPlot({
   x <- as.numeric(strsplit(input$text, split = ",")[[1]])
   ts.obj <- ts(x)
   lowess.obj <- lowess(ts.obj, f = 10)
   plot.ts(x, main = "Sample Time Series", xlab = "Time")
   points(x)
   lines(lowess.obj$y, col = "red")
   legend("top", legend = "Loess Smoother", col = "red", lty = 1)
 })
})
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks you very much for you talent & effort.

Comment: If this solution is the answer to your question please accept the answer otherwise please let us know what we can do to answer your question completely.